# Firebase master detail while having unique keys ionic

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Just started using ionic, angular and firebase. And I'm having an issue creating a master-detail pattern.

**What I want to achieve:**
Have a list on my page that's being retrieved from firebase database. When clicking on of the listitems it should show the details of the selected listitem.

**What I currently have:**
I can save data in firebase database through a form. This is my write operation that I want to get and put it in my list. I'm adding the data in the database with `push()` method of firebase

**My problem:**
I've flattened the data structured as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#flatten_data_structures)

```
MetaData{
    2017:{
      1x48sdf3617SDf542394:{
       name: "someName",
       date: "24/01/2017"
      }
    }
},
fullData{
    2017:{
      8i89gslsdk617SDf542gsLd:{
       name: "someName",
       date: "24/01/2017",
       comment: "someComment",
       required: "true",
       ...
      }
    }
}
```

So in the list, which is the masterpage, I only getting the metaData back. When clicking it should go to the detail page. The detailpage should get the data back from fullData. The problem is how is the mapping between the metadata and the fulldata. because  they both have a unique key generated by firebase.

I looked at some other questions, but they don't have this specific issue as they are defining their own unique key. I don't want to do that, would like to use the auto generated key from firebase.

How would I tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the documentation. I need to use the `update()` method. First creating a key, then using that key in multiple places to save the data using the `data()` method

Check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement in two possible ways :

1. Using the same key for metadata and details. You can store the key in a variable and use the same to write the details. your data structure be like

   /metadata/someKey/ {your javascript object}

   /detail/someKey/ {your detail of metadata}
2. By referencing it from metadata. In this case your data structure will be

/metadata/someKey/{....., details : someKey1}

/details/someKey1

Comment: But both require an extra step from me, isn't it possible to achieve this with just firebase?

Comment: how about adding the reference path in the metadata, that way you can always have a path to look for the details.